# Images as variables in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, variables

I hope the name of my question was explicit enough. Basically I want to upload images to my php code. After some research I figured it had to be written in html.
It was easily done. Now, the image i want to upload changes in lots of cases, so instead of writing hundreds of line using SWITCH and IF, ELSE,... I simply want to introduce the name of my image as a variable (named $string here). Like so:

```html
function displayIcon ($string) {
echo ' 
<html>
<img src="/src/' $string '.png" width="50" height="50" />
</html>
';    
}
```

But I doesnt work,... Is it possible and how do you doit it ??
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
function displayIcon ($string) {
echo ' 
<html>
<img src="/src/' $string '.png" width="50" height="50" />
</html>
';    
}
```

is invalid PHP. You need to concatenate the variable like:

```
function displayIcon ($string) {
echo ' 
<html>
<img src="/src/' . $string . '.png" width="50" height="50" />
</html>
';    
}
```

An alternative approach is to use double quotes for the string encapsulation and single quote for the attribute encapsulation.

```
function displayIcon ($string) {
echo " 
<html>
<img src='/src/{$string}.png' width='50' height='50' />
</html>";    
}
```

I also would not have the `<html>` because I'd think this is being used on already generated page.

You also should get in the habit of checking your error log. You should have been getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$string' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

Which would have pointed you in the right direction. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thank you!!
I am still new to php and web interfaces (but I have awesome plans!!)
I will try to find my error log !